# Conditions in javascript with button

Tags: javascript, button, if-statement, conditional-statements, click

I have two buttons in javascript and I need a condition that checks which button was pressed. I have seen some examples online but it does not work. Does anyone know kindly help me and correct me?

```
if(sx.clicked == true){
// dx.style.backgroundColor = colori[random];
alert("sx");
}

if(dx.clicked == true){
alert("dx");
}
```

Comment: think you're missing a bit there `f(dx.clicked == true)`. Also there has to be more code than that as here it's not showing us much, try to put the code around those lines too.

Comment: it was a mistake to copy and paste but it does not change. I do not recognize if you pressed the button, it seems strange

Comment: Like I said post more code, a couple of `if` is not going to tell us anything about the code around. what are `sx` and `dx` we can only assume and what code set the `clicked` property on them?

Comment: Are you talking about normal buttons or radio buttons? As per my understanding Radio buttons is the right thing you need to implement.

Comment: This [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj3QE/) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it like that. You should define a "click" event - either with the "onclick" html attribute, or with JS - element.onclick or addEventListener.

These ways defines that when the user clicks on an element, a function is executed. You define 2 functions, one for each button. You can read about onclick attribute and element.onclick here : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp, and about addEventListener here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="buttonsHandler(this)">Button1</button>
<button onclick="buttonsHandler(this)">Button2</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonsHandler(evt)
    {
        if(evt.textContent == "Button1")
        {alert("Button1 Clicked");}

        else if(evt.textContent == "Button2")
        {alert("Button2 Clicked");}
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
   for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
      elements[i].onclick = function () {
        alert(this.id);
   }
}
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9PvU5/

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to add the event to button instead of a specific button. But sometimes if you have two/three combo buttons you can try it.

```
<button onclick="buttonsClick(this)" data-attr="btn1">Button1</button>
<button onclick="buttonsClick(this)" data-attr="btn2">Button2</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function buttonsClick(btn)
{
    if(btn.getAttribute('data-attr') === "btn1")
    {console.log("Button1 Clicked");}
    else if(btn.getAttribute('data-attr') === "btn2")
    {console.log("Button2 Clicked");}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the closest method to what you were trying to use, but in correct Javascript:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var button1 = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
      var button2 = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1];

      button1.onclick = function() { /*execute some code here*/ };
      button2.onclick = function() { /*execute some code here*/ };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </body>
</html>
```